# Samsung S3 pattern lock on used phone

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung

How do I get past the screen being locked up with pattern lock for Samsung S3? I just got the phone and has someone else's settings. I just want to get to the basic swipe unlock. If a phone is reset, will it remove the pattern lock, and need to use it? I just want to get into the apps so I can use the device. Right now, I can't even get to the main screen page.

Answer (score 1):

A reset (through the recovery) will remove all data from the user.
If you don't want to preserve that simply follow the short guide:

> (Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvD6ZCENlJA)
>   1. Shut down your device.
>   2. Enter recovery mode by holding *Power, Home and Volume-Up* **at the same time.**
>   3. When the screen turns on you can release the **Power** button. (*keep all other buttons pressed until the recovery comes up*)
>   4. Select *Wipe data/factory reset* from the menu with the *Volume-Up/-Down* buttons.
>   5. Press the *Power* button to select the action.
>   6. Reboot your device. (In case of no auto-reboot do that like you did with the *factory reset*)
>
> First reboot will take some time to set up everything. After that all data is lost, even on the internal "SD card".